# Is DataGrid.ScrollViewer the same as TreeView.ScrollViewer?

Tags: c#, wpf, scrollviewer, material-design-in-xaml

Can anyone tell me if the ScrollViewer in a DataGrid is the same as the ScrollViewer found in a TreeView?
I am testing out a new scrollbar style, but when I apply it to each of the above, it displays on the RIGHT side for the DataGrid but the LEFT side of the TreeView! LOL WTF?!

Here is how I apply the style in each case: (obviously not complete)

```
<TreeView.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ScrollViewer" BasedOn="{StaticResource MyNewScrollbarStyle}">
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ScrollViewer" BasedOn="{StaticResource MyNewScrollbarStyle}">
```

I can post the entire scrollbar style if necessary I just didn't want to post a huge block of code unless necessary.  (Yes I am that new to this site, posting to it anyway)

Many thanks in advance - this is haunting me!

Comment: It's the same control, `System.Windows.Controls.ScrollViewer`, in both cases. I'd look at the contents of the templates and see what they're doing with it: Right click on a TreeView in Design Mode in the XAML editor. Select "Edit Template" | "Edit a Copy". Then you can see what's really going on in there.

Comment: Are you setting flowdirection in either style? Or setting the template differently in each style. If your scrollbar is on the correct side for one then the scrollcontentpresenter must be in the left column for that. The scrollviewer template in the msdn docs moves the scrollbar to the left by putting it in column 0 of it's outer grid.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa970847(v=vs.85).aspx